# Regex lookaround for a group doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

Happy Saturday,

I'm wondering if Stackoverflow's users could give me a clue about one specific Regex..

```
(^visite\d+)(?!\D)
```

The above regex works well..

It says that :

```
visite12345  --> is a good anwser (the string does match)
visite1a     --> is not a good anwser (the string doesn't match)
```

However for:

```
visite12345a --> It doesn't work.
```

Indeed, the output is visite1234, whereas I'd like to get the same answer that for visite1a (string doesn't match)...

I use http://regexr.com/ to test my regexp.

Do you have any idea how to so?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It captures `visite1234` in your first input as well. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `(^visite\d+)(?!\D)` matches `visite` at the start of the string, followed with one or more digits that should not be followed with a non-digit.

The "issue" is that the engine can backtrack within `\d+` pattern and it can match 2 digits if the third is not followed with a nondigit.

The best way to solve it is to check the actual requirements and adjust the pattern.

If the digits are the last characters in the string you just should replace the lookahead with the `$` anchor.

A generic solution for this is making the subpattern atomic with a capturing group inside a positive lookahead and a backreference, and make sure the lookahead is changed to something like `(?![a-zA-Z])` - fail if there is a letter):

```
/^visite(?=(\d+))\1(?![a-z])/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX5hZ0/1)

Or if a word boundary should follow the digits (i.e. digits should be followed with a letter, digit or an underscore), use `\b` instead of the lookahead:

```
/^visite\d+\b/
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX5hZ0/2)

Comment: It solved the problem perfectly. And it's simple... I should have thought about it myself... Thank you!